# What should be my step length if I'm doing a step every T time?

Tags: math

I have a distance **X** that needed to get done in **Y** time.

What should be my **step length** if I'm doing a step every **T** time?

For example: my distance is 360 that should be done in 5sec, taking a step every 10milis, what should be my step length?

What is the equation for this?

Comment: Look up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Y` time and `T` - time for a step. Then you will make `Y/T` steps. So you have to cover distance `X` in `Y/T` steps. Then `yourStepLength = X/(Y/T) = X/Y*T.`

Answer (score 1):

Number of steps is 5 seconds / 0.01 seconds (10 milliseconds) = 500 steps in 5 seconds.

Distance per step = 360/500 = 0.72 units (step length in whatever units you are using).